# What could be reasons for spark job to stuck

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming-kafka

I'm running Spark 2.3.1 standalone cluster.
My job is consuming from Kafka mini batches every 2 minutes and writing aggregation to some store. Job looks like as following:

```
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(...)
stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
   val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
   stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
}

stream.map(x=> Row(...))
.flatMap(r=>...)
.map(r=> (k,r))
.reduceByKey((r1, r2) => r)
.map { case (_, v) => v} 
.foreachRDD { (rdd, time) => // write data}
```

The job was ok and run for almost a week. But then, it stacked - I see that the batches running, but in Kafka there started to be a lag, and also the offsets become to be unchanged.

In the logs, there are the following messages, and I can see that they are repeated every 2 minutes (IMHO, the batch interval). So I suppose that the job hanged due to retries.

```
[org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager] Starting task 14.0 in stage 13042.0 (TID 7732814, 10.9.6.53, executor 5, partition 14, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7846 bytes)
[org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager] Starting task 0.0 in stage 13042.0 (TID 7732815, 10.9.6.77, executor 3, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7846 bytes)
[org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager] Starting task 1.0 in stage 13042.0 (TID 7732816, 10.9.6.61, executor 2, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7846 bytes)
[org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager] Starting task 4.0 in stage 13042.0 (TID 7732812, 10.9.6.65, executor 1, partition 4, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7846 bytes)
[org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager] Starting task 28.0 in stage 13042.0 (TID 7732813, 10.9.6.62, executor 4, partition 28, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7846 bytes)
[org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl] Adding task set 13042.0 with 186 tasks
[org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler] Submitting 186 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 13042 (MapPartitionsRDD[117358] at map at MyAgg.scala:373) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14))
```

The restart solved the problem.
My question - any ideas why did that happen, and what can I do/configure to prevent that from happening again?

Comment: do you have any memory dump? spark needs lot of memory for aggregations

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. The job was restarted. But I didn't saw any logs error for memory